# Crontab: PHP Wget or Curl

Tags: php, curl, wget, cron

I have a question about what command to use to run a PHP script from Crontab.

Which of these alternatives would be the most appropriate to use.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/project/cron.php
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://localhost/project/cron.php
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://localhost/project/cron.php
```

I hope not to bother with my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a PHP script you want to run, in a CLI environment, I'd definitely use `php`.

If you want to run the PHP script in a server environment, use either `wget` or `curl`, but I'd argue that a process task like this should be executed on the CLI.

Comment: This is at least somewhat dependent on the script you are running.  Running via the web interface might be significant for running as the right user, and with assorted environment variables set.  Depending on how the script is written, you might need to go out of your way to make sure all these things are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the first option. When you are running scripts via console, running them directly is always a better idea. Running it via web server can introduce unexpected problems with reliability.